# Is there a way to restart Tomcat on auto-publish in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have a JAX-RS web service that I work on in Eclipse. I have Eclipse set up to build automatically, and I have Tomcat server set up in Eclipse to automatically publish changes ("Automatically publish after a build event").

So that works great, except the service is using JNI and whenever code is published to Tomcat I get in Tomcat console:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library already loaded in
>   another classloader

If I restart Tomcat from the context menu, the deployed code runs fine.

I cannot modify the service as described on [Tomcat website](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#I.27m_encountering_classloader_problems_when_using_JNI_under_Tomcat), so the question is:

Is it possible to setup Tomcat in Eclipse to be restarted before, during or after publish?

Comment: Have you tried hot code replacement tools such as Jrebel?

Comment: No, I am sure Jrebel is great, but it is pricey, and may be a bit of overkill in this case